# How do I change the background color of the ActionBar of an ActionBarActivity using XML?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-theme, android-styles

Details:

I'm extending ActionBarActivity.
Eclipse and SDK fully patched as of 2011-11-06.

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
```

Deployed to Samsung device with Android 2.3.3
Application has `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light"`

**Issue:** application is light, but ActionBar is blue with grey icons, hardly visible against the blue background color. I also want the ActionBar to be light, so they grey icons are more visible.

I've tried modifying the styles but to no avail.
I'm probably missing something trivial.

**How do I change the background color of the ActionBar of an ActionBarActivity using XML ?**

Comment: Closing this old chestnut. Points to Sannidhi, by popular demand, however the replies to this question span quite a few versions of Android, and in my context David Millers suggestion to use SherlockActionBar was most relevant.

Comment: Little tidbit for others: If you make the first element in your XML view the same background as your ActionBar (in our case, white), the ActionBar turns grey.

Comment: When you think about, TitleBar and ActionBar dont offer anything special. They are more like a nuisance, especially when you dont know them. A.better alternative would be to hide them and design your own title bar. You can add your own widgets with Views and drawables. As Title bar provides no widgets. And action bar can only have one drop down list, for all menuItems.Even alot of Apps have ditched Action Bar in favour of their own.

Answer (score 539, accepted):

As per [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) - "You can control the behaviors and visibility of the action bar with the ActionBar APIs, which were added in Android 3.0 (API level 11)."

So, ActionBar will not work for your target environment which is at API level 10 (Android 2.3.3).

Just in case, if you target for minimum API level 11 , you can change ActionBar's background color by defining custom style, as:

```
<resources>
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">ANY_HEX_COLOR_CODE</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

And, set "MyTheme" as theme for application / activity.

Comment: @AlexanderFragotsis use `<item name="android:textColor">@color/my_color</item>`.

Comment: The same approach should be used if you are using ActionBarCompat library. The only difference is that you should change **actionBarStyle** (without *android:* prefix) item to define how actionbar will look on pre-3.0 Android devices

Comment: Is there any possibility to, instead of putting the color's HEX code, reference a `@android:color` or even a custom color defined in `colors.xml`? I've tried it with no success.

Comment: @jmrodrigg use `<item name="android:background">@color/black</item>`

Comment: Actionbar behavior can be changed for api < 11. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024706/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-of-the-actionbar-of-an-actionbaractivity-us/27847656#27847656

Comment: Can you help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28609110/custom-theme-not-applying

Comment: I'm not able to change text action bar text color using "<item name="android:textColor">@color/my_color</item>"

Comment: is it possible to set the color directly in "MyTheme" without creating the additional style tag?

Comment: This didn't work for me with android:background tag but when I left out the android tag and put just <item name="background"> the color changed for all platforms.

Comment: `<item name="actionBarStyle">` and `<item name="background">` pair works for me. I'm using com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0.

Comment: It works, but now this changes my preferences screen background to the same color

Answer (score 219):

Try this

```
ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable("COLOR"));
```

Comment: 11-06 10:53:16.985: E/AndroidRuntime(16956): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.acme.myActivity.getActionBar

Comment: @coder_For_Life22 do you know how can I get a contextual action bar?

Comment: afaik, the support library itself doesn't have the ActionBar, for that you wil have to include the SherlockActionBar.

Comment: maybe this is strange but in my case `bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.BLUE));` change the action bar color to grey. These happens also if put other color, like `Color.RED`, `Color.GREEN` and so on... Does anybody have the same problem, or know the cause of this issue? I use a Nexus S device

Comment: What if I want to align text to center?? `<item name="android:textAlignment">??</item>` what could be the attribute at "??"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17198657/1022454
This post seems to fix the issue where the action bar color goes grey.

Comment: in order to add a Hex color simply use Color.parseColor("#7bb42c").

Comment: @KennyWest Please do not edit an answer with code modifications, they should be comments

Comment: @KennyWest **bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.GREEN));** NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION?

Answer (score 127):

try this:

```
ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#0000ff")));
```

Comment: How does this fit into the rest of the code? just curious where to actually add this

Comment: I have the exact question as @JGallardo . Where do you add this? I tried it in `onCreate` but it gave a `NullPointerException`  Edit: This is the code I added to `restoreActionBar`  

    
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#E5E4E2")));

Comment: Add it your Activity's onCreate method.

Comment: use getSupportActionBar() instad of getActionBar()

Answer (score 69):

Use this - http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/

Its an amazing tool that lets you customize your actionbar with a live preview.

I tried the earlier answers but always had problems with changing other colors like the tabs and letters and spent hours tweaking stuff. This tool helped me get my design done in just a couple of minutes.

[image: Here's a screenshot of the tool]

All the best! :)

Comment: how do I set my app to use the files once they are added into my app?

Comment: In the context of the screenshot above (named example), after pasting the generated res folder, you should have a new style @style/Theme.Example. In AndroidManifest.xml, set <application android:theme="@style/Theme.example">. Should work :)

Comment: deprecated. unfortunately

Answer (score 58):

I had the same problem, where my Action Bar would turn grey when I entered that code. Chances are your original style sheet looked like this:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
</style>
```

The "DarkActionBar" was what was keeping your Action Bar grey. I changed it to this, and it worked:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#2aa4cd</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/Theme.MyAppTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
</style>        

<style name="Theme.MyAppTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
```

I also threw in how to edit the text color. Also, no need to change anything surrounding the resources.

-Warren

Answer (score 39):

## **Behavior of Actionbar can also be changed in APIs < 11**

**See the [Android Official Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html) for reference**

I am building an app with `minSdkVersion = "9"` and `targetSdkVersion = "21"` I changed the color of action bar and it **works fine with API level 9**

Here is an xml

`res/values/themes.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
           parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBar"
           parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">@color/actionbar_background</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="background">@color/actionbar_background</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

and set the color of actionbar you want

`res/values/colors.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="actionbar_background">#fff</color> //write the color you want here
</resources>
```

Actionbar color can also be defined in `.class` file, the snippet is

```
ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#0000ff")));
```

but this **will not work** with the **API < 11**, so styling the actionbar in `xml` is only way for API < 11

Comment: Can you help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28609110/custom-theme-not-applying

Comment: The snippet doesn't work in my app when used in a fragment. I changed it for ActionBar bar = getActivity().getActionBar(); . As soon as fragment is about to be opened it crashes.

Comment: Found the problem, it works with : ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

Answer (score 22):

For Kotlin users - I tried it and this works with light mode and dark mode -

```
    getSupportActionBar()?.setBackgroundDrawable(
             ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#003459"))
        
)
```

Add this in onCreate like this -

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        getSupportActionBar()?.setBackgroundDrawable(
             ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#003459"))
        )
```

Comment: Would be better to use resources to get the color rather than having it as a text.
`getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black)));`

Answer (score 16):

On the Nexus 4 people this seems to make the color go grey.

```
ActionBar bar = getActionBar(); // or MainActivity.getInstance().getActionBar()
bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0xff00DDED));
bar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);  // required to force redraw, without, gray color
bar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
```

(all credit to this post, but it is buried in the comments, so I wanted to surface it here) 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17198657/1022454

Comment: After spending countless hours trying to figure out WTH was wrong, this answer helped me.

Answer (score 14):

try one line code :

```
getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.MainColor)));
```

Comment: My app crashes with this answer. To make it work in a fragment I changed it like this : getActivity().getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.col_nar))); , also tried getActivity().getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.col_nar))); . It crashes as soon as the fragment is opened.

Comment: Found the problem, it works with : ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

Comment: the answer is for the activity. If you want to use it with fragment then  you have to use getActivity().getActionBar() for fragments

Answer (score 9):

2021: Kotlin oneliner with no deprecation:

```
supportActionBar?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.red)))
```

Simply put it into onCreate and change the color depending on your needs

Answer (score 6):

This is how you can change the color of Action Bar.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;


public class ActivityUtils {

public static void setActionBarColor(AppCompatActivity appCompatActivity, int colorId){
    ActionBar actionBar = appCompatActivity.getSupportActionBar();
    ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(getColor(appCompatActivity, colorId));
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);
}

public static final int getColor(Context context, int id) {
    final int version = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (version >= 23) {
        return ContextCompat.getColor(context, id);
    } else {
        return context.getResources().getColor(id);
    }
}
}
```

From your MainActivity.java change the action bar color like this

```
    ActivityUtils.setActionBarColor(this, R.color.green_00c1c1);
```

Answer (score 5):

### When you are Extending Activity use following Code

```
ActionBar actionbar = getActionBar();
actionbar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable("color"));
```

### When you are Extending AppCompatActivity use following Code

```
ActionBar actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
actionbar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable("color"));
```

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes this option throws NullPointerException

`ActionBar actionbar = getActionBar();
actionbar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable("color"));`

But this option is worked for me. So you can try this.

```
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF")));
```

Happy Coding

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me, for AppCompatActivity,

```
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/BlackActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="BlackActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="background">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/BlackActionBarTitleTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="BlackActionBarTitleTextStyle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/cinzel_decorative</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using androidx AppCompact. Use below code.

```
androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable("Color"));
```

Answer (score 2):

This code may be helpful

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- customize the color palette -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/material_blue_500</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/material_blue_700</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/material_blue_500</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/black</item>

</style>
<style name="CardViewStyle" parent="CardView.Light">
    <item name="android:state_pressed">@color/material_blue_700</item>
    <item name="android:state_focused">@color/material_blue_700</item>
    <!--<item name="android:background">?android:attr/selectableItemBackground</item>-->
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

Its very simple for those who are using API 21 or greater Use this code below

## for Dark ActionBar

```
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorDarkGrey</item>
</style>
```

## for_LightActionBar

```
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorDarkGrey</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use This code ..to change action bar background color.
open "res/values/themes.xml" (if not present, create it)
and add

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
       parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>
 <!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar"
       parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
</style>
```

Note : this code works for android 3.0 and higher versions only

Answer (score 0):

Use this, it would work.

```
ActionBar actionbar = getActionBar();
actionbar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable("color"));
```

Answer (score -2):

```
getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.TabColor)));
```

color.xml file:

```
<resources> <color name="TabColor">#11FF00</color> </resources>`
```