# Change actionbar color programmatically more than once

Tags: android

I am using

```
getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0xff00ACED));
```

To change the color of my action bar in a fragment and it works. But if i open this fragment then open another fragment that calls this method with a different color the actionbar doesn't change to the desired color. Instead it turns to a white color instead of the color I set it to.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

this is a quick fix that i found

```
mActionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0xff00DDED));
mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
```

Comment: This only happened for me on one device... The blasted Motorola Xoom. However, this fixed the problem!  In my case, toggling the display of the title needed to be reversed since I was not showing the title to begin with.

Comment: I can confirm this also fixed the issue on an LG-P880g. You my friend, are amazing! Thank you!

Comment: I had to use a color resource when using the support action bar.                         getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.swift)));

Comment: Now ActionBars are long gone. Everybody uses Toolbars now

Comment: getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#363C54")));

Answer (score 46):

**Try this,**

**Method1:**

```
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0xff00FFED));
```

**Method2:**

```
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources()
                    .getColor(R.color.bg_color)));
```

**Method3:**

```
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#3A1212")));
```

**Kotlin**

```
supportActionBar?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(this, android.R.color.black)))
```

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem, [answer from user1634451](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17198657/2631260) worked but only once (would not enable several color switches in a row)

This definitely fixed it:

```
bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources()
                    .getColor(R.color.app_bar_online)));
```

Instead of directly linking to the color doing `new ColorDrawable(R.color.app_bar_online)`

Comment: I'm using `ContextCompat` instead of `getResources`, though, because I'm using the support library. Also, `getResources().getColor(int)` is deprecated now.

Answer (score 11):

getColor is deprecated. use ContextCompat :

```
bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.app_bar_online)));
```

Comment: Thanks. In case if anyone picking color from color-array then use **bodyColor[index]** instead **ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.app_bar_online)**.

Comment: Using this solution, I get a NullPointerException at this point (even a warning from AS). Why?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to set the color of the ActionBar and have the color as a String, this seems to work for me.

```
    getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
            new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#993b3c4e")));
```

You may have to enable & disable the title to get it to refresh/display properly like in the answer given by [user1634451](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17198657/2631260), but I didn't need to in my case.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to avoid deprecation you can used

```
val mActionBar: ActionBar? = supportActionBar    
mActionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.red)))
```

Kotlin Language

Answer (score -1):

If you want want to change actionbar color or background pragmatically then simply use,

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.white_background));
            }
```

white_background.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="#fff" />
```

Answer (score -1):

((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary)));

In the fragment and Java

Comment: Please instead of just writing a piece of code, try to explain what it does and why it would work.