# Android SDK, action bar color

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-actionbar, oncreate

So in my app I have the action bar color code as this in the create event of the "activity_main":

```
android.app.ActionBar redd = getActionBar();
redd.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#BA0202")));
```

And it changes,But I'd like to use a string. I have tried "R.string.ColorRed"
In replacement of the "#BA0202", and it gives me an error.
The reason why I want to do this and not change my app theme is because when the user clicks a button it will change the action bar color to a specific color. And another reason why I want to use the string is because if I have this code on multiple pages I would have to change the color code (#BA0202) to a different one on every page if I wanted to change the -Main Theme Of The ActionBar color-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your

```
redd.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#BA0202")));
```

to

```
redd.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(getResources().getString(R.string.ColorRed))));
```

and to fixed the problem thats causing this [Change actionbar color programmatically more than once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17076958/change-actionbar-color-programmatically-more-then-once/17198657#17198657)

append this code to your actionbar :[assumng this problem existed in your app]

```
redd.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
redd.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
```

hope it helps :)