# How to chage the color of actionbar in android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am newbie to android and i am working on a demo related to actionbar and fragments,I have done with it but now i want to change the colour of my actionbar,I have tried below link which gives me exception,

[Change Color of Actionbar in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26459243/change-color-of-actionbar-in-android)

So,Can anybuddy helps me to do it?

Thanks in advance,Dont close it as i couldnt find any solution so far.So i request you to guide rather than close the question.

Comment: Did you try to change `ColorPrimary` iand `ColorPrimaryDark` in colors.xml?

Comment: @Lalit - You can help me better to ran for reputation points and marking as duplicate..!!!

Answer (score 1):

I think that this answer will fit all your requirements - [change-color-of-actionbar-in-android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9249702/3874721).
You simply need to modify your Theme.

Comment: Used with no luck...!!! :(