# Changing the Action Bar Colour in Different Activities

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I wanted to have different coloured action bars in each activity but after searching on the internet, I couldn't find anything. I was wondering if this is even possible and if so how?

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/17198657/4848308

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change actionbar color programmatically more than once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17076958/change-actionbar-color-programmatically-more-than-once)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you need a parent activity with `setActionBarColor` method.

```
public class ParentActivity extends ActionBarActivity/*or similar*/ {

    public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
        super.onCreate(state);
    } 

    public void setActionBarColor(Color color) {
        getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(color));
    }
}
```

And extends each activity from this

```
public class ActivityA extends ParentActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
        //call ParentActivity.onCreate(state)
        super.onCreate(state);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_a);
        // some initialization code
        setActionBarColor(Color.rgb(248, 248, 248));
    }
}

public class ActivityB extends ParentActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
        // some initialization code
        setActionBarColor(Color.rgb(248, 248, 248));
    }
}
```

Comment: The activity seems to crash on launch. I'm I right in thinking that the second bit of code goes in the actual activity?

Comment: @ZakWoolley here is a inheritance principle in action. When you start each activity it will call parent methods, without crash if you will not use objects related to childs.

Comment: @ZakWoolley yes. Actually here is a your activities, that you was declared in manifest and implemented.

Comment: I don't think I quite understand what you're saying. Have I got to call the parent activities' on create method from the main activities' on create?

Comment: @Zak Woolley yes. You will call.