# Failed to change custom actionbar background color in android

Tags: java, android, tabs, android-actionbar

I am creating an android application where in one activity I was displaying tabs with the help of actionbar, So I have to change actionbar background color. But whenever I am trying to change the background color it will display either white background or black background. So how can I modify the action bar to change its background color?

**Below is my activity code:-**

```
public class SavedRecord extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener{

    private ActionBar actionBar;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;

    String[] tabs = {"Audio","Video"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.saved_record);

        //initialization
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setIcon(null);
        actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setTitle("Saved Record");
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#ff7043"));
        actionBar.setStackedBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);
        for (String tab_name:tabs){
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name).setTabListener(this));
        }

        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }
}
```

**And the screenshot of the activity:-**

[image]

Comment: have you tried this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17076958/change-actionbar-color-programmatically-more-than-once

Comment: Yes, I tried that one also but it doesn't work properly, it has turned actionbar background color to white. @MohitSuthar

Comment: @GRV_Droid Any progress so far?

Comment: Yes, I got the solution for above problem @W3hri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are using the "regular" ActionBar.

Try to use the SupportActionBar by importing

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
```

and calling

```
actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
```

I think this should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change using style of your App

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
     <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarStyle</item>
     </style>

     <style name="ActionBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">/*your custom color*/</item>
     </style>
</resources>
```