# Change toolbar color with a ripple effect when swiping a viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have implemented all my ViewPager listeners. So I was wondering if anyone knows how can I achieve the toolbar color change including the ripple effect that google has implemented on the PlayStore - you can see the effect when you swipe to Movies, Music, Books fragment on the PlayStore. How can I achieve that? Thank you

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/17198657/7337723

Comment: Ok thank you and for the ripple effect, do you have an idea?

Comment: http://www.tothenew.com/blog/ripple-effect-in-android/ might help you

Comment: for a ripple effect library, consider picking from: https://android-arsenal.com/search?q=ripple