# How to make globally background of the Action Bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm a noob in android development and I need to set the background color of the ActionBar globally. The whole application will be the same ActionBar background. Can I make this by using AndroidManifest.xml, if yes how? Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK, you can declare a custom style for your ActionBar and define that in your manifest. Or you could create a base Activity class, from which  all your other Activities will derive..and define the ActionBar background there.

Comment: Please,can you explain widely?How I can understand declare a custom style for your ActionBar?

Comment: Are you using the native ActionBar or the ActionBarSherlock library?

Answer (score 0):

To make global variables...

1. Make a new class and add your variables (Add whatever value you need in this class)

   ```
   package com.srr.yourpackage;

   public class GlobalVariables extends Application{

       private int someVar;

       public int getSomeVar(){
           return someVar;
       }
       public void setSomeVar(int a){
           someVar = a;
       }

   }
   ```
2. Add the reference of this file to your Manifest inside the application tag.

   ```
   <application
   android:allowBackup="true"
   android:debuggable="true"
   android:icon="@drawable/icon"
   android:label="@string/app_name"
   android:name =".GlobalVariables">
   <activity.....
   </application>
   ```
3. Use it inside any of your classes.

   ```
   public class yourNewClass extends Activity
   {
        GlobalVariables globalVar;

        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.yourLayout);
        globalVar = (GlobalVariables) getApplication();
        int yourInt = globalVar.getSomeVar(); //Call upon anything you need in the activity of your choice.
        }
    }
   ```

Or if you only need just Action Bar, use [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024706/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-of-the-actionbar-of-an-actionbaractivity-us)

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather prefer to make a theme and customize each `activity`, or the `application` in the manifest file. When I develop apps, I use this tool to generate the UI:

[Android Action Bar Style Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/)