# Editing Holo Light with Dark Action Bar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme

I like the holo light theme, but want to change the colors around a bit. So, I want to change the background on the action bar from black to orange. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I change the background color of the ActionBar of an ActionBarActivity using XML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024706/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-of-the-actionbar-of-an-actionbaractivity-us)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom style which you can add to your theme.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
<style name="MyActivityTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <!-- other activity and action bar styles here -->
</style>

<!-- style for the action bar backgrounds -->
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <!-- Use a color attribute defined in colors.xml -->
    <item name="android:background">@color/orange</item>
    <!-- Or use a regular color code (This is orange)-->
    <item name="android:background">#F3D3D</item>
</style>
```