# How to set custom ActionBar color / style?

Tags: android, colors, background, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

I am using `Android Navigation bar` in my project,
I want to change the top color in action bar to something red, How can i do that?
I have something like this,

[image: top black]

and i want something like this,

[image: top red]

how can i achieve that?

Answer (score 183, accepted):

You can define the color of the ActionBar (and other stuff) by **creating a custom Style**:

Simply edit the **res/values/styles.xml** file of your Android project.

For example like this:

```
<resources>
    <style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarTheme</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">ANY_HEX_COLOR_CODE</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**Then set "MyCustomTheme" as the Theme of your Activity that contains the ActionBar.**

You can also set a color for the ActionBar like this:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.RED)); // set your desired color
```

Taken from here: [How do I change the background color of the ActionBar of an ActionBarActivity using XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024706/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-of-the-actionbar-of-an-actionbaractivity-us)

Comment: What do you mean by "Then set "MyCustomTheme" as the Theme of your Activity that contains the ActionBar." How do I do that?

Comment: In your activity XML you must add *android:theme="@style/MyCustomTheme"* as a paremeter inside the <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager... /> tag

Comment: what about remaining valuesv14 and valuesv21 styles.xml files in android

Comment: How would one go about changing the title textStyle?

Comment: @KalaJ use ```setTheme(R.style.MyCustomTheme)```  in the onCreate method of your activity.

Answer (score 65):

In general Android OS leverages a “theme” to allow app developers to globally apply a universal set of UI element styling parameters to Android applications as a whole, or, alternatively, to a single Activity subclass.

So there are three mainstream Android OS “system themes,” which you can specify in your Android Manifest XML file when you are developing apps for Version 3.0 and later versions

I am referring the (APPCOMPAT)support library here:--
So the three themes are 
1.  AppCompat Light Theme **(Theme.AppCompat.Light)**

[image]

2. AppCompat Dark Theme(Theme.AppCompat),

[image]

3. And a hybrid between these two ,AppCompat Light Theme with the Darker ActionBar.( Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar)

AndroidManifest.xml and see the  tag, the android theme is mentioned as:-- **android:theme="@style/AppTheme"**

Open the Styles.xml and we have base application theme declared there:--

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
  </style>
```

We need to override these parent theme elements to style the action bar.

**ActionBar with different color background:--**

To do this we need to create a new style MyActionBar(you can give any name) with a parent reference to **@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse**  that holds the style characteristics for the Android ActionBar UI element. So definition would be

```
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="background">@color/red</item>
</style>
```

And this definition we need to reference in our AppTheme, pointing to overridden ActionBar styling as--

> @style/MyActionBar
>   [image: ActionBar with pink background color]

**Change the title bar text color (e.g black to white):--**

Now to change the title text color, we need to override the parent reference **parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">**

So the style definition would be

```
<style name="MyActionBarTitle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

We’ll reference this style definition inside the **MyActionBar style definition**, since the TitleTextStyle modification is a child element of an ActionBar parent OS UI element. So the final definition of MyActionBar style element will be

```
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="background">@color/red</item>
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitle</item>
</style>
```

SO this is the final Styles.xml

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!-- This is the styling for action bar -->
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="background">@color/red</item>
        <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBarTitle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

[image: ActionBar With white title color]
 For further ActionBar options Menu styling, refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32324319/1234913)

Comment: hey man it worked . one doubt what if i want change the color of menu overflow icon ,it changes the color according our theme right ?. white icon for dark theme and dark icon for light theme ,how can i change it to white ? consider the last image in your answer.

Answer (score 33):

**For Android 3.0 and higher only**

When supporting Android 3.0 and higher only, you can define the action bar's background like this:

res/values/themes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
       <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
  <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
       <item name="android:background">#ff0000</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

**For Android 2.1 and higher**

When using the Support Library, your style XML file might look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <resources>
  <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
 <style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar"
       parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
  </style>
 </resources>
```

Then apply your theme to your entire app or individual activities:

for more details [Documentaion](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html)

Comment: This is strange: you give android 3.0 and higher an older style (holo) than 2.1 and higher (Material Design / Appcompat)...

Comment: @DalvikVM Yeah..Appcompat is for older versions. no need to use it for higher versions. At the time of this answer material design was not instroduced.

Comment: I'm getting an error: `No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse'.` Changing it to `android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse` solves the problem. Thanks.

Comment: @style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar cant be resolved in my case (Android Studio) - should it not be @android:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar - i.e. with a prepended "android" before the style ?

Answer (score 32):

You can change action bar color on this way:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/green_action_bar</item>
</style>
```

Thats all you need for changing action bar color.

Plus if you want to change the status bar color just add the line:

```
 <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/green_dark_action_bar</item>
```

Here is a screenshot taken from developer android site to make it more clear, and here is a [link](https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html#ColorPalette) to read more about customizing the color palete

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Another possibility of making.

actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#0000ff")));

Answer (score 5):

I can change ActionBar text color by using titleTextColor

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="titleTextColor">#333333</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 4):

Custom Color:

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">

                <item name="colorPrimary">@color/ColorPrimary</item>
                <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/ColorPrimaryDark</item>
                <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
     </style>
```

Custom Style:

```
 <style name="Theme.AndroidDevelopers" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:selectableItemBackground">@drawable/ad_selectable_background</item>
        <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/MyPopupMenu</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/MyDropDownListView</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabStyle</item>
        <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/MyDropDownNav</item>
        <item name="android:listChoiceIndicatorMultiple">@drawable/ad_btn_check_holo_light</item>
        <item name="android:listChoiceIndicatorSingle">@drawable/ad_btn_radio_holo_light</item>
    </style>
```

For More: [Android ActionBar](http://viralandroid.com/search/label/ActionBar)

Answer (score 3):

As I was using `AppCompatActivity` above answers didn't worked for me. But the below solution worked:

**In *res/styles.xml***

```
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

PS: I've used **`colorPrimary`** instead of **`android:colorPrimary`**

Answer (score 1):

in the style.xml add this code

```
<resources>
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyAction</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">#333333</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```