# Custom item inside style

Tags: android, styles, themes, items

I would like to know if is it possible to add custom items inside of a style.

For example:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="color5">@color/myColor</item>
</style>
```

Comment: yes its possible check example here but you can not use your own attributes https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/blob/master/example/res/values/styles.xml

Comment: @DhawalSodhaParmar that aren't custom item. I can use already <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">, but "color" doesn't exist

Comment: check this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/18288460/1168654

Comment: I dont search that, he is creating custom item to an specify element, I want to create a general color for all elements.

Comment: http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/#name=example&compat=holo&theme=light&actionbarstyle=solid&texture=0&hairline=0&neutralPressed=1&backColor=33b5e5%2C100&secondaryColor=D6D6D6%2C100&tabColor=33B5E5%2C100&tertiaryColor=fb3%2C100&accentColor=33B5E5%2C100&cabBackColor=93c%2C100&cabHighlightColor=9c0%2C100

Comment: i think you got your answer...

Comment: Nop, you are giving me how to change specify elements, I don't want that. I already have that indeed. I want to create a custom item. Pass me a code with an item called "color5" with a random color... because I don't understand how can I get this with your links.

Comment: In that link you ll get idea how make theme for app then you have to develop you own them... If you want to create custom them like you pass color n passed color apply on theme then you have to go thru java code xml theme not help you..