# change the background of an action bar on an activity that extends ActionBarActivity

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar, android-actionbaractivity

I'm trying to change the action bar background color of an activity that extends ActionBarActivity. So far my styles.xml looks like this

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#ff2b8bff</item>
</style>
```

And I call on the style in my manifest like this

```
 android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

The problem is that the action bar is always grey,it never changes to the color I have specified.I know there is a lot of information on questions like this already but none of them have worked for me.I'm just wondering what it is I am missing.

Comment: which api are you using?

Comment: Use it this way http://stackoverflow.com/a/18288460/3498044

Comment: @Ryan unfortunately this leads to the error "You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity."

Comment: What you're using `ActionBarActivity` or `Activity`?

Comment: I'm using ActionBarActivity

Comment: Change that to `Activity`. Here's the reason : http://stackoverflow.com/a/21815015/3498044

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@color/red</item>
    <item name="background">@color/red</item>
</style>
```

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23155637/change-background-color-of-the-action-bar-using-appcompat/23156002#23156002).

Answer (score 0):

> The reason you are having this problem is because the activity you are
>   trying to apply the dialog theme to is extending `ActionBarActivity`
>   which requires the `AppCompat` theme to be applied.
>
> Change the Java inheritance from `ActionBarActivity` to `Activity` and
>   leave the dialog theme in the manifest as it is.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21815015/3498044