# Android unable to change background color of ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm trying to change the background color of my Actionbar, but after referencing the [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024706/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-of-the-actionbar-of-an-actionbaractivity-us) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18288402/how-to-set-custom-actionbar-color-style?lq=1) questions on this site I still can't get their solutions to work.

**Styles.xml**

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.Solid">
        <item name="background">@color/light_blue_menu_bar</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**colors.xml**

```
<resources>
    ... 
    <color name="blue_semi_transparent_pressed">#80738ffe</color>
    <color name="light_blue_menu_bar">#87CEFA</color>
</resources>
```

**manifest.xml**

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

However the ActionBar doesn't appear in of my views. What am I missing?

**EDIT**

The solution was to add to styles.xml

```
<item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
```

[image]

Comment: What version(s) of Android are you targeting?

Comment: i'm targeting 22, with a min of 19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarStyle</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarStyle</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="background">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/blue</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I updated my question to include the relevant part of my manifest.xml. I'm primarily using fragments, but my main activity does extend ActionBarActivity.

Comment: What about activity tag theme? are you sure you are not using  getActionBar().hide(); or requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); also try     
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>  in AppTheme

Comment: adding <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>  will cause the ActionBar to appear, but it is the default Dark theme, not the light blue that I configured in the styles.xml

Comment: that change also generates the dialogue "Rendering Problems. Missing Styles. Is this the correct theme for the chosen layout? Use the theme combo box above the layout to choose a different layout... failed to find style with id 0x7fff0002 in current them"

Comment: So we fix the first issue to show your action bar i will edit the answer to show you full example how to set your color,

Comment: Please upload another screen shot because i don't recognize pop up problem

Answer (score 1):

You can use this,

```
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#Color_Code")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should edit `styles.xml` at  `values-v14` folder.Because your min version is 19.