# Is it possible to change AppBar text color in my theme (AppCompat)?

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I want to change only the AppBar text color, but in the Theme Editor (I use Android Studio) I can only change `textColorPrimary` (it changes AppBar text color but also the LargeText color).

My current theme:
[image]

I can change only textColorPrimary:
[image]

Now I change the text color like this:

`style.xml`

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

`activity.xml`

```
...
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        ...
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
           ...
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

        ...

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Is it possible to change text color in my AppTheme in `style.xml`?

Comment: simply use this : `yourToolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.parse("#ffeeeeee"));`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26548766/1318946

Comment: Or define a style for your appbar such as in this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/18288460/4706693

Comment: Try to check this: http://www.androiddocs.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html See section "Customize the Text Color".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create a custom theme which has as parent your desired base theme,
   such as `ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar`.
2. Add customizations to the theme. For title color it will be
   `textColorPrimary`. For overflow and icons it will be `textColorSecondary`.

Then use the custom theme you created to set theme for your toolbar.

Comment: does not work. I have set textColor, titleTextColor, and android:textColorPrimary to black but the title is still white.

Answer (score 2):

`@color/colorForeground`

You can just add "`colorForeground`" attribute in styles for changing the foreground color in appbar. This also changes the text colour and the color of the menu dots.

Or you can use the theme editor to edit the colors.