# Drawable in background ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have a gradient of two color in a shape and I wanted to put this in the actionBar of my application preferably in style because I want all the applicationbar to have this visual.

I try this

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.ActionBar" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/shape_toolbar</item>
    </style>
```

but failed

How I can do that?

Comment: I find a response for my problem here https://stackoverflow.com/a/18288453

Answer (score 0):

You can switch to `Toolbar` instead of the standard `ActionBar` and then apply a style with `android:background` to it, almost the same as you did.

Can you make this changes by yourself? Here is a good guide about it: [Codepath](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-the-App-Toolbar)