# How to prevent Action bar from flickering when removing logo an setting title programaically

Tags: android, android-actionbar, flicker

How to prevent Action bar from flickering when removing logo an setting title 
programatically

Below is the code I have in my MainActivity.java. This changes the action 
bar. But it first displays the actual action bar with logo and title I have 
given in Android Manifest.xml. Then the action bar flickers and changes to 
new title and no Logo.How to remove flickering and make Action bar load at 
once ?

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setLogo(null);
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
actionBar.setTitle("Welcome Dear User");
actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

I tried with style.xml route also

**Android Manifest.xml:**

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/geniusicon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

**Style.xml:**

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>

    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">#20a780</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/Theme.MyAppTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.MyAppTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:textColor">#ff0000</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: You can look at here. https://antonioleiva.com/collapsing-toolbar-layout/

Comment: I think you didnt get my question. I am having a app. I have first page. In the first page, the action bar initially shows logo and title from Android Manifest.xml. But after that the action bar flickers and new action bar  is shown. It doesnt have icon as I have removed it in java class. Is it possible to avoid this and have single action bar.

Comment: Oh, i got it right now. Then, you should be create theme in styles.xml. Look at this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/18288460/5580210

Comment: I tried that too. PFB my Android Manifests.xml and style.xml. But with this my action bar disappears.