# AppCompatActivity ActionBar styling without using Toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout, appcompatactivity

I've got AppCompatActivity that is not using Toolbar.
I'm trying to style my SupportActionBar in this activity, by setting a proper theme. The theme below doesn't work (when assigned to Activity in AndroidManifest)

```
<!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
       parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar"
       parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
</style>
```

Only changing colorPrimary works (changes the color of SupportActionBar).

My question is - where is the style of SupportActionBar derived from? How to assign theme to AppCompatActivity properly?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18288402/how-to-set-custom-actionbar-color-style

Comment: First of all for AppCompat we need to inherit from parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
But then it doesn't work anyway. And I don't want to change color only but the styling (like background drawable). I didn't see any way to do that without using Toolbar yet. Question is - is it possible at all?

Comment: http://www.androiddocs.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html
Has a partial answer in the Note section at the start of document. Anyone got that working? I couldn't find appcompat.R.attr properties. How does the code look like?

Comment: try this `@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light`

Comment: I have update android studio and I have the same bug so thank for the question

Comment: Check there https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr