# Android: how to change action bar background color?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-actionbar

The color of my android application is black. I wish to change it to other color. What is the easiest way to do it? I have tried to make a theme from this [link](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/#name=blue&compat=holo&theme=light&actionbarstyle=solid&texture=0&hairline=0&backColor=d0effa,100&secondaryColor=D6D6D6,100&tabColor=33B5E5,100&tertiaryColor=F2F2F2,100&accentColor=33B5E5,100&cabBackColor=FFFFFF,100&cabHighlightColor=33B5E5,100)

When the application is opened, I could see that the action bar has changed the color from black to other color but in about 3 seconds, there is a message: Unfortunately, .... has stopped. I wish to use an easier way to may it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To apply the theme to all activities, change the style.xml like this:

```xml
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarTheme" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@color/action_bar</item>
</style>
```

And in colours.xml, use:

```xml
<color name="action_bar">#BA0000</color>
```

And in the manifest:

```xml
<application
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

Comment: First of all, I wish to thank you for your kind reply. I tried your suggestion and in the styles.xml file, I get this error message:error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'android:background' with value '@color/action_bar'). I think I might have made some mistakes and it would be great if you could give me some suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I changed the @color/action_bar to a hex color code and it works fine. I feel really grateful to you. However, I still hope that you could point me the possible reason for the problem I have stated in the above comment. :)

Answer (score 4):

if you want change the color of  `ActionBar` just do this:

```
 ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
 bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable("COLOR"));
```

see the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024706/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-of-the-actionbar-of-an-actionbaractivity-us) for more info

Comment: I am just a very beginner. May you be so kind to tell me where shall I add the above code? In the xml file? Or in the java file?

Comment: in the java file and in `onCreat()` method

Comment: Only problem with this code is that it causes a NullPointerException error. Do you know any ways to avoid this?

Comment: @Arshia you can check bar is not equal to null, you need check that ( `if ( bar != null` ) then set background

Comment: @shayanpourvatan That's awesome, thanks!