# How to change the background colour of the action bar

Tags: java, android, xml, android-activity, android-actionbar

I want to change the background colour of the action bar and maybe the text colour too. This question has already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024706/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-of-the-actionbar-of-an-actionbaractivity-us) but I do not understand it.
 Do I need to make a new xml file with this:

```
 <resources>
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">ANY_HEX_COLOR_CODE</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

And where should I save it? what folder?
and how to set this as my theme?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, save it in the theme.xml file under res->value folder

Comment: you can put in respective `res/values/styles.xml`

Answer (score 0):

You should save this xml into values folder, like themes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">ANY_HEX_COLOR_CODE</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

And you should select this theme in AndroidManifest like:

```
<application android:theme="@style/MyTheme">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way... simple create a new color xml in drawable folder..

somecolor.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<color xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:color="#e03456">
</color>
```

then in onCreate:

```
    getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.somecolor));
```

if you wish to change text color:

```
 int titleId = getResources().getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id","android");
          TextView yourTextView = (TextView) findViewById(titleId);
       yourTextView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you change the color of Action Bar (only a few steps):

1. Use Android Action Bar Style Generator to general all style xml for
   your application. It's a web tool,
   http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html.
   The web allows you to generate styles (color, background ... etc)
   necessary for the Action Bar. Here is the screen shot of the web
   tool. [image]
2. The tool generates sample
   resources icons, images, style xml as the followings. Add all
   resource files to the application resource drawable area, and update
   AndroidManifest.xml application:theme to use the style xml generated
   from the tool. The following is the sample styles, images created
   from the tool. [image]
3. I put all xml in res/drawable folder, except for the action bar style file. I put the action bar style file in res/values. The style file contains this line:
       `<style name="Theme.Example" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">`
4. Update your AndroidManfest.xml to use the action bar style "Theme.Example" in the main activity which has the action bar.

   ```
   <activity
       android:theme="@style/Theme.Example"
       android:name="com.example.restaurant.MainActivity"       
       android:label="@string/app_name" >
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
       </intent-filter>  
   </activity>
   ```
5. The following is the styled action bar I generated for my project. [image]