# how to change android default eclipse actionbar tab background?

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar

i have created the new project in eclipse file->new->other->android application project

in this navigation type i gave action bar tab with view pager, i eclipse automatically created with actionbar with tabs, what i need is want to change the actionbar bg and tab bg and tab indicator bg,i have changed actionbar background color no problem in that, but i have no idea about changing the actionbar tab background color and that default tab indicator blue color?

Here is my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
    ActionBar.TabListener {

SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Set up the action bar.
    final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

    View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar, null);
    TextView mTitleTextView = (TextView) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.title_text);
    String text = "<font color=#3e4093>Save</font> <font color=#ed3338>life</font>";
    mTitleTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
    actionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                }
            });
    for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                .setIcon(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getIcon(i))
                .setTabListener(this));

    }
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    public Drawable getIcon(int position) {

        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_home);
        case 1:
            return getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_info);
        case 2:
            return getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_more);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return new firstTab();
        case 1:
            return new secondTab();
        case 2:
            return new ThirdTab();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take this as reference

[How do I change the background color of the ActionBar of an ActionBarActivity using XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024706/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-of-the-actionbar-of-an-actionbaractivity-us)

You style file should look like this

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
         <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
         <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">#1ADEDB </item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Change Tab background Color
http://www.technotalkative.com/android-change-tab-bar-background-color/

This tool seem to be nice for generate style for action bar.

http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/

Comment: this style for above version 11 and  not changing the actionbar tab background colr

Answer (score -1):

i have used this link and using this link i have changed the actionbar tab background color its useful thanks @BlaShadow

Change Tab background Color http://www.technotalkative.com/android-change-tab-bar-background-color/