# How to change action bar background color

Tags: android, android-actionbar

How to Change color in action bar background color using programatically in android

Using setBackgroundDrawable this property.

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024706/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-of-the-actionbar-of-an-actionbaractivity-us?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already mentioned method in your question

Use it as:

```
ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("##CC66FF")));
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 methods.

---

Method 1 -

In res/values/styles.xml, you can define it like this -

**For Android 3.0 and higher**

```
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
       parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar"
       parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">ANY IMAGE OR HEX COLOR</item>
</style>
```

**For Android 2.1 and higher**

```
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
       parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar"
       parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
</style>
```

Then apply your theme to your entire app or individual activities:

```
android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme"
```

---

Method 2 -

To change it programaically, try this -

```
ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable("HEX COLORS"));
```

---

Docs - [Styling the Action Bar](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
       ActionBar ab = getActionBar(); 
       ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#81a3d0"));     
       ab.setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);
```

[have look this also](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can use a [ColorDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ColorDrawable.html)

```
 ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable();
 colorDrawable.setColor(yourColor);
```