# Changing android actionbar color?

Tags: android, colors, android-actionbar

I set the color to white but it won't change:
activity_my.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MyActivity"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

</RelativeLayout>
```

style.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
    </style>
    <style name="ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">#ffffff</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

androidmanifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="eu.test.test.test" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MyActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I've searched, but everywhere is explained this way.

I've added the androidmanifest file.

Comment: ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable("COLOR"));

Comment: It returns error can't be applied with this color - #ffffff, or rgb variant.

Comment: r u using sharelack activity on simple activity

Comment: ActionBar ab = getActionBar(); 
           ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#81a3d0"));     
           ab.setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);

Comment: You'll probably find the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024706/ helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Dont forget to use your created `AppTheme` in the `AndroidManifest` as applicaton/activity theme (**not** in  the `relative layout`).

Example to set your application theme :

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

Comment: Have you delete android:theme="@style/AppTheme" from your relative layout?

Comment: Again it doesn't change its color.

Comment: Sorry man. i cant see whats wrong in your code. Just checked my code and what i did is exactly like yours. Try to clean the project and run again

Answer (score 0):

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
  </style>
<style name="ActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/dark_grey</item>
</style>
```

You haven't put in style tag "parent". You can try it !