# How to change colour of actionbar in different activities?

Tags: android, eclipse, background-color, android-appcompat, android-actionbar-compat

My min api level is 8. I am using app combat themes. So doing extends activity in every .java file.

Does anyone know how to change the background color of the actionbar when opening a new activity?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in your activities:

```
ActionBar ab = getActionBar(); 
ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#81a3d0"));     
ab.setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);
```

see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024706/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-of-the-actionbar-of-an-actionbaractivity-us) and [here](http://androidsbs.blogspot.in/2013/08/change-background-color-on-action-bar.html).

Comment: Inside onCreate(). But see the links for other techniques.