# Change status bar text color when primaryDark is white

Tags: android, android-styles, android-statusbar

I am trying to reproduce the behaviour of Google Calendar application:
[image]

but I have not found a way to change the status text color. If i set the colorPrimaryDark as white I cannot see the icons neither text of status bar due their color is white as well.

Is there any way to change the status bar text color?

Answer (score 271, accepted):

I'm not sure what API level your trying to target, but if you can use API 23 specific stuff, you can add the following to your AppTheme styles.xml:

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
```

when `android:windowLightStatusBar` is set to true, status bar text color will be able to be seen when the status bar color is white, and vice-versa
when `android:windowLightStatusBar` is set to false, status bar text color will be designed to be seen when the status bar color is dark.

Example:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <!-- Status bar stuff. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item> 
</style>
```

Comment: if my api level is 21 it is not working can you tell me the alternative for that

Comment: Any solution found for Api 21. Please help?

Comment: Note: android:windowLightStatusBar requires API level 23 (current min is 21) more... (⌘F1)

Comment: For api 21 this is not possible. In google applications it's a black bar rather than a white.

Comment: See this post for API Level < 23: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49254877/white-navigationbar-with-grey-icons/49255140#49255140

Comment: `<item name="android:windowLightNavigationBar" tools:targetApi="o_mr1">true</item>` also fits good with this answer.

Comment: @BastiVagabond It is not solution, it just suppresses the warning. It still won't work on API < 23

Comment: For API 21+ see example below with WindowInsetsControllerCompat

Answer (score 39):

you can do that programmatically like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31963003/2978334)

just add this

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);
```

Comment: setSystemUiVisibility is deprecated

Answer (score 33):

The compat version [works on API 23+](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/view/WindowInsetsControllerCompat#setAppearanceLightStatusBars(boolean)).

Here it is:

```kotlin
// deprecated
// WindowInsetsControllerCompat(window, view).isAppearanceLightStatusBars = Boolean
// also deprecated
// ViewCompat.getWindowInsetsController(view)?.isAppearanceLightStatusBars = Boolean
WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, decorView)?.isAppearanceLightStatusBars = Boolean
```

You can get `window` directly from an `Activity`.

I like to add it to `Window` extension methods:

```kotlin
fun Window.setLightStatusBars(b: Boolean) {
    WindowCompat.getInsetsController(this, decorView)?.isAppearanceLightStatusBars = b
}
```

You need `androidx.core` for this

Comment: Ace -> Nice! Thank you!

Comment: This method has no effect on API <23. https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/view/WindowInsetsControllerCompat#setAppearanceLightStatusBars(boolean)

Answer (score 29):

it's very simple:

```java
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);//  set status text dark
getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(BookReaderActivity.this,R.color.white));// set status background white
```

and vice versa:

```java
getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(BookReaderActivity.this, R.color.black));
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView(); //set status background black 
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(decorView.getSystemUiVisibility() & ~View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR); //set status text  light
```

Answer (score 17):

Following @Jon's answer I would update it a little but on new apis. On new apis with themes and night themes (dark mode) I would do it by adding the v23/styles.xml and set the status bar background and text color there:

```xml
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/lightColor</item>
<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
```

And in the night/styles.xml:

```xml
<item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">@color/darkColor</item>
<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar" tools:targetApi="m">false</item>
```

The default styles.xml wouldn't contain any of this code, or just this, but remember to not set it to light:

```xml
<item name="android:statusBarColor">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
```

This way we are setting the light background (and text color) for status bar but only for devices with api 23+. On devices <23 background will not be changed, as I think this is something that we dont want knowing that the text color will stay white.
The dark theme was added on API 29, so we don't have to be afraid of dark theme on api 21 ;)

The drawback of this however is that we are adding another file that we will need to remember to manage.

Answer (score 4):

As previous, the SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR do the work in my case, don't forget to set for higher than API 22.

add this to oncreate after the setContentView:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

With API 21+, this works for me:

```
WindowInsetsControllerCompat windowInsetsController =
                WindowCompat.getInsetsController(getWindow(), getWindow().getDecorView());
windowInsetsController.setAppearanceLightStatusBars(true);
```

I use

```
Theme.AppCompat.DayNight
```

and this code works for the Day and for the Night mode:

```
getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getWindow().getNavigationBarColor());
WindowInsetsControllerCompat windowInsetsController =
                WindowCompat.getInsetsController(getWindow(), getWindow().getDecorView());
if ((getResources().getConfiguration().uiMode & Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK) == Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO)
            windowInsetsController.setAppearanceLightStatusBars(true);
        else
            windowInsetsController.setAppearanceLightStatusBars(false);
```

Comment: true answer is here

Answer (score 3):

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);//  set status text dark

getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this,R.color.colorPrimaryDark));// set status background white
```

It works for me

Comment: This requires API level 23+.

Answer (score 2):

Try this once.

In your activity `onCreate()` method, paste the following code.

```
try {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
                Window window = getWindow();
                window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
                window.setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.color_red));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Note: color_red - is the status bar colour.

Comment: The question is about the text color of the status bar, not the status bar background.

Answer (score 2):

In your activity `onCreate()` method, paste the following code after the `setContentView(R.layout.activity_generic_main);`

Here is the sample code below.

```
public class GenericMain extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_generic_main);
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this if not splash page

```
getActivity().getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);
getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);
getActivity().getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
getActivity().getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.white));
getActivity().getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.white));
```

Answer (score 2):

To have a white status bar and black text color do this (Kotlin):

In the `onCreate` function of your main activity add this

```
val window: Window = window
WindowInsetsControllerCompat(window,window.decorView).isAppearanceLightStatusBars = true
```

In **`resoursces/styles.xml`** add this

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">#ffffff</item> <!-- this line sets the status bar color (in my case #ffffff is white) -->
<!-- the following lines are not required -->
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

**This works with API level 21 as well.**

Answer (score 1):

COMPOSE:

I had a problem when changing theme from dark to light and vice versa.
These lines of code worked for me:

```
val view = LocalView.current
val window = (view.context as Activity).window
window.statusBarColor = rememberedColors.surface.toArgb() //Some Color
WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, view).isAppearanceLightStatusBars = isSystemInDarkTheme().not()
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone in the future looking to change status bar color from white programmatically in a fragment and back to primary dark when leaving fragment for minimum api 21< 23 in android using Java

```
private void updateStatusBar(boolean isEnter){

    Window window = requireActivity().getWindow();

    int color = ContextCompat.getColor(requireActivity(),R.color.colorAlertDialog);

    if(isEnter) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            window.getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);
        else
            clearDecorFlags(window);
    }
    else {
        color = ContextCompat.getColor(requireActivity(),R.color.colorPrimaryDark);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            window.getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(window.getDecorView().getSystemUiVisibility() & ~View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);
        else
            clearDecorFlags(window);
    }
    window.setStatusBarColor(color);
}

private void clearDecorFlags(Window window){
    window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
}
```

Comment: Override text color?

Answer (score 0):

**So it's a bit different in case of kotlin**

```
//for Dark status bar icon with white background

    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR)
            getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.white))    
    
             
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR.inv())
            getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.black))

 // for dark background and light theme colours of icon.
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you are trying to change color of icons and texts in the status bar, to dark color so those get visible, you can do this, keep in mind this have to be done OnViewCreated of the Fragment

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        activity?.window?.let {
            WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(it, true)
            WindowInsetsControllerCompat(it, view).isAppearanceLightStatusBars = true
        }
    } else { // deprecated method for older versions
        var flags: Int = view.systemUiVisibility
        flags = flags or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR
        view.systemUiVisibility = flags
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For future readers

If you have enabled edgeToEdge then you can use this.

For dark content color

```
enableEdgeToEdge(
        statusBarStyle = SystemBarStyle.light(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT, android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT)
    )
```

You might be facing this because your device has dark mode enabled and you are drawing your custom background in status bar, this happens because by default enableEdgeToEdge uses SystemBarStyle.auto for statusBarStyle.

Don't forget to put enableEdgeToEdge before super.onCreate() of the activity.