# Android - change text color

Tags: android

I want to change text color to black in the circled area as seen in the image below. How can I do it?

[image]

Comment: does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38382283/change-status-bar-text-color-when-primarydark-is-white

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin I checked your answer and it doesn't answer my question