# Xamarin Status bar text color

Tags: ios, xamarin, statusbar

I need help in changing the text color of Xamarin app in the status Bar because when Changing the status bar color to white the text color stays white, thus not appearing.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8LWy.png)

Comment: please post the relevant code

Comment: Your question has an iOS tag so why does your image show an Android emulator?

Comment: Because i am running the application on android emulator. -matt

Comment: I am asking for the relevant code -Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code in `style.xml` when you change status bar color .

```
<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
```

This makes the text will always appear whatever the background color is .

[image]

Refer to

[Change status bar text color when primaryDark is white](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38382283/change-status-bar-text-color-when-primarydark-is-white).