# How to change status bar icon color in Android?

Tags: android, colors, icons, statusbar

I want to change status bar icons color from white to black. I try below code but I can't make it. Could you help me please?

Activity Code:

```
public static void setLightStatusBar(View view,Activity activity){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

        int flags = view.getSystemUiVisibility();
        flags |= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR;
        view.setSystemUiVisibility(flags);
        activity.getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.WHITE);
    }
}
```

style.xml code:

```
<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
```

Comment: You want to change icon color . Are `Time` and other icon in the top ?

Comment: @KeLiuyue Yes. I want to change status bar text and icon color.

Comment: Have a look at  [this answer(Make the status bar white with black icons).](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74375368/2289835)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this .

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    activity.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility( View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN|View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);
    // edited here 
    activity.getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.WHITE);
}
```

Then set at the root layout

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

**Another way**

Try this in your code .

```
public static int StatusBarLightMode(Activity activity) {
    int result = 0;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        if (MIUISetStatusBarLightMode(activity, true)) {
            result = 1;
        } else if (FlymeSetStatusBarLightMode(activity.getWindow(), true)) {
            result = 2;
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            activity.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);
            result = 3;
        }
    }
    return result;
}


public static boolean FlymeSetStatusBarLightMode(Window window, boolean dark) {
    boolean result = false;
    if (window != null) {
        try {
            WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = window.getAttributes();
            Field darkFlag = WindowManager.LayoutParams.class
                    .getDeclaredField("MEIZU_FLAG_DARK_STATUS_BAR_ICON");
            Field meizuFlags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.class
                    .getDeclaredField("meizuFlags");
            darkFlag.setAccessible(true);
            meizuFlags.setAccessible(true);
            int bit = darkFlag.getInt(null);
            int value = meizuFlags.getInt(lp);
            if (dark) {
                value |= bit;
            } else {
                value &= ~bit;
            }
            meizuFlags.setInt(lp, value);
            window.setAttributes(lp);
            result = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
    return result;
}

public static boolean MIUISetStatusBarLightMode(Activity activity, boolean dark) {
    boolean result = false;
    Window window = activity.getWindow();
    if (window != null) {
        Class clazz = window.getClass();
        try {
            int darkModeFlag = 0;
            Class layoutParams = Class.forName("android.view.MiuiWindowManager$LayoutParams");
            Field field = layoutParams.getField("EXTRA_FLAG_STATUS_BAR_DARK_MODE");
            darkModeFlag = field.getInt(layoutParams);
            Method extraFlagField = clazz.getMethod("setExtraFlags", int.class, int.class);
            if (dark) {
                extraFlagField.invoke(window, darkModeFlag, darkModeFlag);
            } else {
                extraFlagField.invoke(window, 0, darkModeFlag);
            }
            result = true;

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                if (dark) {
                    activity.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);
                } else {
                    activity.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Then use `StatusBarLightMode(this);` in your code .

And it can make your status text and icon to be black .

**Edit**

Starting with Android 6.0, Google official provides support for configuring `android:windowLightStatusBar` in the style property
Yes, when set to true, when the background color of the statusbar is light, the text color of the statusbar becomes grayed out for false.

```
<style name="statusBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light">
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/status_bar_color</item>
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">false</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Unfortunately It doesn't work. My phone is OnePlus One. Android version is 6.0.1

Comment: You can try again . @MuhammedCobanoglu

Comment: Could you try second way in your code ? I use HUA WEI and is ok . Also you can try @MuhammedCobanoglu

Comment: I tried with Samsung A3 2017. It worked. Thanks for everything.

Comment: @MuhammedCobanoglu ,Good luck to you!

Answer (score 2):

This did it for Android version >= 21:

```
activity.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR
    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);

activity.getWindow().setStatusBarColor(0x000000);
```

Comment: this really worked!! I don't know WHY? my issue was that i needed write status bar and setting only `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR` made the screen layout disappear on API 23 (only!)

Answer (score 0):

Make status bar icon color black

```
getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowInsetsController().setSystemBarsAppearance(APPEARANCE_LIGHT_STATUS_BARS, APPEARANCE_LIGHT_STATUS_BARS);
```

Maker status bar icon color white

```
getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowInsetsController().setSystemBarsAppearance(0, APPEARANCE_LIGHT_STATUS_BARS);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this. make status bar icon color black with Java**

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                View decor = getWindow().getDecorView();
                boolean shouldChangeStatusBarTintToDark = true;
                getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.WHITE);
                if (shouldChangeStatusBarTintToDark) {
                    decor.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);
                } else {
                    // We want to change tint color to white again.
                    // You can also record the flags in advance so that you can turn UI back completely if
                    // you have set other flags before, such as translucent or full screen.
                    decor.setSystemUiVisibility(0);
                }
            }
```