# how to modify the action bar color scheme as in instagram

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to change the action bar color and text color as in Instagram. Because when I make a gray color, the icon and the time are not clear.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using this code,

```
<style name="statusBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light">
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/status_bar_color</item>
<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">false</item>
```

its not my code and  i got  this from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46131907/how-to-change-status-bar-icon-color-in-android).

Comment: my Project minSdkvesion 21

Comment: @Hasan you'll have to put this in res/values-v23/styles.xml

Comment: Thank you. <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar" tools:targetApi="23">true</item>

Answer (score 0):

According to the guidelines, Starting with Android 5.0 all Notification icons must be entirely white.

The only way to have a colored icon is to lower your targetSdkVersion to values <21, but I think you would do better to follow the guidelines and use white icons only.

If you still however decide you want colored icons, you could use the [DrawableCompat.setTint](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/graphics/drawable/DrawableCompat.html) method from the new v4 support library.