# Android black and white theme

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, android-theme

i am trying to achieve theme like this but i can't find any help about it i am trying to get white action bar with black icons and text and status bar with black icons and white background I am changing color pragmatically but I think there is some proper theme to get something like this i have also tried `material.theme.light` [image: androdi black and white theme]

Comment: Are you using custom toolbar ? @Mateen

Comment: no android's tool bar

Comment: what's the problem in changing `colorPrimary` and `colorPrimaryDark` to white to achieve your desired theme ?

Comment: @VivekMishra if i change colorPrimaryDark to white status bar icons remains white and cant be seen thats problem in it

Comment: How about this https://i.stack.imgur.com/auSbY.png

Comment: @NileshRathod see my above comment

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46131907/how-to-change-status-bar-icon-color-in-android. That too is possible , check the link

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android statusbar icons color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30075827/android-statusbar-icons-color)

Comment: @VivekMishra i know this can be done pragmatically i am asking if there is any proper theme

Comment: you haven't mention that in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your Solution

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/ar_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Nilesh Rathod"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Theme

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <item name="colorControlNormal">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">false</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">#000</item>

</style>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: its working fine but menu items icons color is still white how can black them also?

Comment: its `CoordinatorLayout` but menu items icons color is still white

Comment: @MateenChaudhry make sure your rootlayout is `CoordinatorLayout`

Comment: no dear i can't find any solution to change icons color

Comment: @MateenChaudhry have u added this `<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>` in your theme because for me its working fine

Comment: its working fine i am saying about toolbar's icon like settings icons its color is still white

Comment: @MateenChaudhry `toolbar's icon like settings icons its color is still white` can u share that code how u added icon in toolbar

Comment: <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@color/colorWhite"
                            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                             />

Comment: @MateenChaudhry can u add that code in your question