# Is there any way to make white status bar with dark icons for api 21 and 22 in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-theme

I'm trying to implement a white status bar with grey/dark icons just like Instagram. I have used `<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>` for API >= 23. But what should I do for API 21 and 22?

I am trying to implement something like this

[Here is the image what I am trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtUi7.png)

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/54302579/7666442

Comment: Thanks for the help. I just checked this but `android:windowLightStatusBar` do not work for API 21 or 22.