# Change the background color of both the actionbar and the rest of the activity

Tags: android, android-styles

In continues to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024706/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-of-the-actionbar-of-an-actionbaractivity-us), I'd like to change the colors of both the actionbar (the upper pane)to one color and the rest of the screen to a different color. 
How can I do it?
when I tried this -

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>        
        <item name="android:background">#ffffd982</item> 
</style>
```

it seems like the 'android:background' definition override also the actionbarstyle definition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, the `background` attribute is known to supersede the `actionBarStyle` attribute. However, changing the color of the entire `Activity` needs to be done through the `Activity`'s XML layout, using the `android:background` attribute of the parent `ViewGroup`. The `ActionBar` styles won't help you there.

In your `Activity`'s root `ViewGroup`, set the `background` attribute as:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/outermost_viewgroup"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background = "#00FF00"
    ....
    ....
```

**EDIT:**

I just realized that there *is* a way for this:

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background</item>
```

Add the above tag to to your `ActionBar` style definition, and the `background` in the `colors.xml` file:

```
<resources>
    <color name="background">#00FF00 </color>
</resources>
```

There, done!

Comment: Hi, I want to set the background for ALL the activities of my application, not for a single activity

Comment: I completely forgot that there's a way to do what you want ... please see edited answer!

Comment: The 'android:windowBackground' tag didn't effect the 'android:windowBackground' style but when I put your suggested item in my main Theme definition it worked. But you were close enough and I simpathies you, so I accept this answer

Answer (score 0):

To change Actionbar style In your style.xml file define style like bellow

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
```

```
<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background"><YourColor></item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle"><Your String Color></item>
</style>
```

In your menifest.xml file used your style inside application tag like bellow

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

And for set background color of your activity just set android:background attribute in your each activity like

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ff2323"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginTop="121dp"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

I think this is work for you...!