# Options menu not appearing in Sony Xperia Z

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, android-optionsmenu, sony-xperia

I have an Android application where an options menu is essential for setting up some preferences values.

Here `minimum SDK version` is 8 and the `xml` for the menu is like below.

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/mainmunu_setting"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_preferences"
    android:title="@string/settings">
</item>
```

In Samsung devices I can open the menu as there is a menu button, but in Xperia Z there is no menu button and the the menu is not visible on the `ActionBar` either as the `ActionBar` is not customizable for `SDK version` 11 or below according to this:

[How do I change the background color of the ActionBar of an ActionBarActivity using XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024706/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-of-the-actionbar-of-an-actionbaractivity-us)

How can I have a menu appearing on Sony Xperia Z.

**On Xperia Z device**
[image: On Xperia Z device]

**On Samsung Galaxy S Duos 2 device**
[image: On Samsung Galaxy S Duos 2 device]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If your app is targeting API level 11+ then the menu dots will disappear. By targeting API 8 then you should find the overflow menu appears on the navigation bar of the Xperia Z. I'd highly suggest though targeting a higher level API and actually increasing your minimum SDK since a small percentage of devices now use SDK level 8 or less.

Comment: Thanks Pete. Will try that and the app actually is targeted from API level 8 to higher.