# How to change Toolbar Color with different views?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar

I am setting up my Toolbar in my main activity and trying to change the background color with different fragments.
So basically, I am trying to access the Toolbar object inside fragment and set different background color. 
Few things which I have tried to do is :

Access toolbar like:
((ActionBarActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundColor(XXX);

But I am unable to access the setBackgroundColor function inside fragment. It is perfectly working inside the Main Activity.

Comment: Create a method in Main Activity and Call that method from each fragment.

Comment: change background color when action occur from mainactivtiy click and write the code in mainactivtiy action listener.

Comment: @MrSmith You mean to do it though callback methods?

Comment: @nitinku5021a A simple static method will do . No need to implement a Callback. Just use a plain static method.

Comment: @MrSmith Worked like a charm. Reworked everything :) Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable("COLOR"));
```

or

```
ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#0000ff")));
```

Have a look [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024706/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-of-the-actionbar-of-an-actionbaractivity-us) or [This](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html)

Comment: Tried my life out, the color is getting changed but weird thing is: If I set it red, it becomes blue and so on. I think somewhere the color is getting mixed i.e Red is getting painted over something. I even tried of removing the color altogether but no success. I will look into this in more detail and will post back.

Comment: Have a look this for reference, http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#AdvancedStyles

Comment: or Try this=> bar.getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.rgb(248, 248, 248)));

Comment: Hey I found 1 Solution related to your Issue... Try this...    ===>>  mActionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0xff00DDED));
mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

Comment: Finally it worked !! Thanks a lot Chirag !!   android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = ((ActionBarActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#F44336")));

Answer (score 2):

It is very easy to change the ToolBar, Actionbar color.

```
ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable("COLOR"));
```

or

```
   ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
    bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#0000ff")));
```