# Change toolbar color on fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar, navigation-drawer

I've been trying to change the toolbar color when a selection of the menu is made. I'm working with Fragment, I've been reading a lot of the solution here on stack overflow but none of them seems to work. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

I'm trying to change the color with a switch onNavigationItemSelected() of the MainActivity class.

So far I've only been able to change the color of the navigation bar and status bar but not toolbar or tabs bar.

[image]

If more info is need it just ask for it! thank you!

**MainActivity.class**

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;

    NavigationView navigationView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
        if (navigationView != null)
            navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new AppBarMainFragment())
                .commit();

        updateToolbar(getString(R.string.perfil));
    }

    public void updateToolbar(String title) {
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        if (toolbar != null)
            toolbar.setTitle(title);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toogle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar,
                R.string.open_drawer, R.string.close_drawer);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toogle);
        toogle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int itemId = item.getItemId();
        LinearLayout rl = findViewById(R.id.header_wrapper);
//        AppBarLayout abl = findViewById(R.id.fragTabs_Background); Do not work
//        Integer colorTo = getResources().getColor(R.color.colorFacebook); Do not work

        Fragment fragment = null;

        switch (itemId) {
            case R.id.nav_home:
                fragment = new AppBarMainFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_facebook:
                BaseViewPagerAdapter adapter = new BaseViewPagerAdapter(
                        getSupportFragmentManager(), new String[] {"Siguiendo", "Seguidores"});

                fragment = AppBarMainWithTabsFragment.getInstance(adapter, getString(R.string.facebook));

//                setActionBar(getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorFacebook))));
//                abl.setBackground(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorFacebook)));
                rl.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorFacebook));

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21){
                    getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorFacebook));
                    getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorDarkFacebook));
                }

                break;
            case R.id.nav_twitter:
                BaseViewPagerAdapter adapter1 = new BaseViewPagerAdapter(
                        getSupportFragmentManager(), new String[] {"Recomendadas", "Miembro", "Tuyas"});
                fragment = AppBarMainWithTabsFragment.getInstance(adapter1, getString(R.string.twitter));
                break;
            case R.id.nav_instagram:
                View view = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
                Snackbar.make(view, "Se ha pulsado para abrir las configuraciones.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
                    .commit();
        }

        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Fragment**

```
public class AppBarMainWithTabsFragment extends Fragment {

    private BaseViewPagerAdapter adapter;

    private String title;

    public static AppBarMainWithTabsFragment getInstance(BaseViewPagerAdapter adapter, String title) {
        AppBarMainWithTabsFragment fragment = new AppBarMainWithTabsFragment();
        fragment.adapter = adapter;
        fragment.title = title;
        return fragment;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.app_bar_main_with_tabs, container, false);


    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        ViewPager viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        MainActivity mainActivity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
        mainActivity.updateToolbar(title);
    }


}
```

**Layout** This is the layout for barTool with Tabs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragTabs_Background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Update**

I read the solution suggested by *Nilesh Rathod* on the comments but I don't understand how to implemented.

I just tried the solution suggested by *Hardik Kanak* on the comments and I'm getting this errors

```
    --------- beginning of crash
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.socialhub, PID: 9027
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.socialhub.MainActivity.onNavigationItemSelected(MainActivity.java:80)
        at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView$1.onMenuItemSelected(NavigationView.java:170)
        at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:840)
        at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:158)
        at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:991)
        at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$1.onClick(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:352)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5280)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21239)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:234)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5526)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Application terminated.
```

I also tried the solution of *Mohamad Mahdi Farzaneh* but I get this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.socialhub, PID: 14964
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.socialhub.MainActivity.onNavigationItemSelected(MainActivity.java:80)
        at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView$1.onMenuItemSelected(NavigationView.java:170)
        at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:840)
        at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:158)
        at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:991)
        at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$1.onClick(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:352)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5280)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21239)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:234)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5526)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Beside the errors I'm also getting warnings about "uses or overrides a deprecated API". Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Check this answer you will get hint https://stackoverflow.com/a/54647423/7666442

Comment: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29298454/how-to-change-toolbar-color-with-different-views) Please check above referral link.

Comment: @Marcin I'm sorry did I gave too much information or more information is needed ?

Comment: @HardikKanak I tried your suggestion but i get error. Please see update, thank you!

Comment: Can you please post your layout for toolbar? xml file

Comment: @Faisal I just posted ! Thank your for your  time!

Comment: @Faisal inside a case of the switch at "onNavigationItemSelected()" of the MainActivity.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a problem in your code. 
give your toolbar class scope not method. declare your toolbar as you declared NavigationView and drawyer layout outside **updateToolbar()** method.

```
Toolbar toolbar;
```

then initialise it like this:

```
toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
```

and then you'll be able to change colour:

```
toolbar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
```

Comment: Ok, I'll have to modify all my fragments because it is giving me error, because now they can't find the updateToolbar(). But I'll do the changes...

Answer (score 0):

you can add this line to your activity

`toolbar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));`

Comment: This solution give me error, I just updated the question with the error I'm getting.

Answer (score 0):

If you have space on the fragment, add toolbar inside the fragment and use the activity theme as Appcompat.noactionbar.
Don't use the toolbar of activity. It is a much longer task. Besides if you want to add somefunctionality inside of toolbar it will be a little bit difficult from fragment to adding functionality to activity toolbar.

**Short cut**:- use 1 toolbar for 1 fragment and remember which kind of toolbar you are using. Android support version toolbar or regular toolbar

Comment: Sounds interesting... perhaps I'll give it a try... I'll let you know...

Comment: I use that all the time because changing toolbar in the activity is too much pain.

Comment: And if you want to change in activity spacifically use static mathods in mainactivty  with predefined colors.