# Changing the colour of ActionBar in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-theme

Here is my xml code in styles.xml to change theme and colour of ActionBar.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar"
    parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:icon">@drawable/brand_logo</item>
    <item name="android:background">#ff5d44</item>
</style>
```

Here is the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html). My app supports API level 11 and higher. Not sure where I am going wrong. Please help.

Comment: Try `<item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>` @Narayanarao

Comment: Tried this but no change in the action bar.

Comment: Are you using `toolbar`? @Narayanarao

Comment: Set `<item name="colorPrimary">@color/YourColor</item>` @Narayanarao

Comment: I am sorry, What is the difference between Action bar and tool bar?

Comment: `ActionBar` is not used anymore in new material design. `Toolbar` is used instead. Try setting `<item name="colorPrimary">@color/YourColor</item>` to your theme. It will solve your problem @Narayanarao

Comment: colorPrimary requires API level 21.

Comment: Yes. You are implementing app using Appcompat which required TargetSDk version and compile version to 21. @Narayanarao

Comment: Change TargetSDK version and compile version to 21. @Narayanarao

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using support library. So here is the fix.

```
<style name="MyActionBar"
        parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">#ff5d44</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>

         <!--Support library compatibility-->
        <item name="background">@color/orange</item>
        <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: It is quite curious that you write a question about the background color of the actionbar, and you check as correct a your answer that is not the best answer. The current appCompat (v21) uses the answer reported by @Anirudh.

Answer (score 1):

set "AppTheme" as theme for application / activity.

```
 <!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>

</style>
```

For more check [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024706/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-of-the-actionbar-of-an-actionbaractivity-us) ,[THIS](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html) and [THIS](https://gist.github.com/ricardoalcocer/8152522)

Comment: This removes the existing action bar.

Comment: @Anirudh how it can be `NoActionBar`?

Comment: @Anirudh He is not asking for `Holo` themes.

Comment: @NarayanaraoR check my new anser plz and see if it helps

Comment: This throws an error. "You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity."

Comment: @NarayanaraoR its obvious  from the error that u are using appcompat ,Try this instead @style/Theme.AppCompat.Light or check the new answer