# Android changing ActionBar color when onResume is called

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I've a option in my Preference Screen to changing the `ActionBar` background color.

It works, but by changing the color, I must close and reopen the app to see the changes.

I have to put the `ActionBar` color changing code in `onResume`. But `onResume` not called by `onBackPressed`.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);
    Misc.setActionBarColor(getActionBar(), null);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private SharedPreferences settings;

private OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener listener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    listener = new OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
                String key) {
            //Set Your action bar color here.
            //based on arguments
            //String key == android:key="pref_key"(where this is your PreferenceView)
        }
    };
    settings.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);
}
```

Comment: @ScionofIkshvaku yeah, just a simple listener.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the color of the ActionBar (and other stuff) by creating a custom Style:

Simply edit the res/values/styles.xml file of your Android project.

For example like this:

```
<resources>
    <style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarTheme</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">ANY_HEX_COLOR_CODE</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Then set "MyCustomTheme" as the Theme of your Activity that contains the ActionBar.

You can also set a color for the ActionBar like this:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.RED));
```

For more info https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html

Comment: My actionbar color is changing, but not by going back to the activity.

Comment: Store the color in preference and update the color based on the status of the preference. You can put this code in onResume() of Activity

Answer (score 0):

You can change action bar color like this:
[How do I change the background color of the ActionBar of an ActionBarActivity using XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024706/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-of-the-actionbar-of-an-actionbaractivity-us)

And if you want to restart your activity without showing any animation you can do like this:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sai Phani gave you a good answer. If you wanna change the color programmatically depeding on your preferences, you can also put something like this in **onResume()**:

```
SharedPreferences mysettings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String st1 = mysettings.getString("COLOR_KEY", "default Value here");

if(st1.equals("Blue")){ //Blue example 
  //Change action bar color 
  //Set new value in your preferences
} 
if(st1.equals("Red")){ //Red example

}
```

specify the color by doing this:

```
bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#0000ff")));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are changing the action bar color from PreferenceScreen, then you should also update this changed color value of action bar somewhere like SharedPreferences or some variable. Use getter/setter for setting action bar colors using this variable in your onResume method.