# Changing Background and text color of AppCompat Light DarkActionBar Theme on android

Tags: android, customization, android-theme, android-appcompat

I have used AppCompat Light DarkActionBar Theme for my App.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">        
</style>
```

[image]

Is it possible to change the background color and text color of this ActionBar ? If yes, how ?

Comment: Do you want to change text and background color of the window or the action bar?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I change the background color of the ActionBar of an ActionBarActivity using XML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024706/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-of-the-actionbar-of-an-actionbaractivity-us)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The following code will allow you to completely style the action bar.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.AppTheme.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppTheme.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarPopupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppTheme.PopupMenu</item>
</style>
```

Override the action bar *style* to change the background color or elevation.

```
<style name="Widget.AppTheme.ActionBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.Solid">
    <!-- action bar background - without android prefix -->
    <item name="background">...</item>
    <!-- action bar elevation - without android prefix -->
    <item name="elevation">4dp</item>
</style>
```

Override the action bar *theme* to define special behavior for all views inside the action bar such as action items, ripple background color, text color.

```
<style name="ThemeOverlay.AppTheme.ActionBar" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <!-- title text color -->
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">...</item>
    <!-- subtitle text color -->
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">?android:textColorPrimary</item>
    <!-- action menu item text color -->
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">?android:textColorPrimary</item>
    <!-- action menu item icon color -->
    <item name="colorControlNormal">?android:textColorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

You can also change the popup theme.

```
<style name="ThemeOverlay.AppTheme.PopupMenu" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">
    <!-- popup menu background - NEVER "android:background" !!! in themes -->
    <item name="android:colorBackground">...</item>
    <!-- popup menu item text color -->
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">...</item>
</style>
```

On the other hand, the following code will allow you to style *the window*.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- window background - NEVER "android:background" in themes !!! -->
    <item name="android:windowBackground">...</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">...</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">...</item>
</style>
```

You can also change text color on the action bar directly. **But beware! This will not afffect text color of menu items or icons or ripple color!** This is probably not what you want in the long run.

```
<style name="Widget.AppTheme.ActionBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.Solid">
    <!-- title text color -->
    <item name="titleTextColor">?android:textColorPrimary</item>
    <!-- subtitle text color -->
    <item name="subtitleTextColor">?android:textColorSecondary</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Why a simple thing like changing the title color has to be so damn complicated? I wonder how many Android developers actually understand the breakdown in this xml

Comment: Thanks @EugenPechanec. What about changing `statusBar` color?

Comment: @Antonio Hello, before asking a question always use the search bar. Someone else may have asked the same question already (and in this case they have).

Comment: Thanks, @EugenPechanec. Actually it was intended to suggest you to add it to your answer and have a more complete answer :)

Comment: Hi @EugenPechanec : thank you for your answer, can you please explain what you mean by "The Lazy and Bad Way... that will break when you change color schemes."? I am not sure to understand in which case this will break.

Comment: @Mouss Hmm, it's not apparent in the way I wrote the sample. If you used concrete colors as `titleTextColor` and `subtitleTextColor` and then changed theme from dark to light or the other way around then it would be noticeable. My line of thought is this: The action bar style should only ever use theme attributes so you shouldn't need to override `actionBarStyle`. Only `actionBarTheme` which supplies `colorPrimary`, `android:textColorPrimary` and `android:textColorSecondary`. I'll rewrite the answer so it's less biased.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to change the color of the text on the action bar. Add this in your activity's onCreate:

```
 actionBar.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#ffff00'>Your Title</font>"));
```