# Android actionbar color doesnt change

Tags: android, material-design

I have the following `styles.xml`:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Main theme colors -->
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Where `primary` is defined as:

```
 <color name="primary">#9c27b0</color>
```

However in the preview the actionbar is still black and not deep purple.
When i open the theme editor the actionbar is also deep purple.
Is this a bug in the preview? Or have i done something wrong?
In general how exactly do i use the `styles.xml`? Can i also define button's in it?

Comment: you should use **toolbar** to see effect. also make sure your AppTheme is set in your AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29957822/changing-background-and-text-color-of-appcompat-light-darkactionbar-theme-on-and

Comment: Better to use `Tool Bar` to see **effects** of `colorPrimary`.

Comment: what are you seeing in real device ? black ?

Comment: @SagarNayak yes black

Comment: is this happening with all activity or any specific one ?

Comment: Is your activity in the manifest using the style?

Answer (score 0):

After editing the color code in the color.xml file, you should rebuild it. Try rewriting the code and then rebuilding. I faced the same problem, that's ho