# AppCompat Light DarkActionBar Text color

Tags: android-layout, android-actionbar, android-theme

I am trying to set the Action Bar text color to black in a Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar, but the text color stays white.

Below is my styles resource

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/ActionBar.Title</item>
    <item name="android:subtitleTextStyle">@style/ActionBar.Subtitle</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Subtitle">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"        parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

I also added

```
        android:titleTextColor="@color/black"
        android:subtitleTextColor="@color/black"
```

in the

That did not work.

I tried the answer in [Changing Background and text color of AppCompat Light DarkActionBar Theme on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29957822/changing-background-and-text-color-of-appcompat-light-darkactionbar-theme-on-and) that did also not work.

Can the Title color be set in this theme, or do I need to change to a different theme?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem changing the toolbar text color. The solution was setting the android:textColorPrimary.

Try this:

```
<style name="ActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/red</item>
</style>
```

And then add `android:theme="@style/ActionBar"` to your Toolbar.