# Change actionbar background and title color

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-xml, android-styles

I am new to Android development. The app on which I am working requires white action bar background and the title should be black in color. I am using support library for lower compatibility.

Style.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
     <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: Are you using the new Toolbar as Actionbar?

Comment: Please check the below link to use Toolbar over deprecated action bar
https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/

Comment: I am not using the ToolBar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Styles : Main App Theme

```
<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/CustomActionBarStyle</item>
  <!-- Support library compatibility -->  
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/CustomActionBarStyle</item>

</style>
```

Setup styles for text and background color

```
<style name="CustomActionBarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>

    <item name="background">@color/white</item>
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>
</style>
```

Setup TextColor **Impt:** parent must `@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title`

```
<style name="MyActionBarTitleText" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/action_bar_text_color</item>
</style>
```

For more refer links posted in @Santosh Shinde post

Answer (score 3):

Use This to change title `color`

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
         actionBar.setTitle(Html
         .fromHtml("<font color='#ffffff'> Now playing </font>"));
```

and for action bar title

```
getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
         new ColorDrawable(Color.rgb(0, 0, 0)));
```

or

```
getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
         new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#000000")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this style:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/Button</item>
    <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/EditText</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/black</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@color/core_other_light</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@color/core_other</item>
    <item name="android:background">#00ff00</item>
</style>
```

You can find more information [**here**](https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html) and [**here**](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html).

Comment: Thanks but i am getting error as i am using min sdk as 9

Comment: change your min sdk level to 11

Comment: I client needs it to be 9

Comment: The same approach should be used if you are using ActionBarCompat library. The only difference is that you should change actionBarStyle (without android: prefix)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024706/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-of-the-actionbar-of-an-actionbaractivity-us/27847656#27847656