# How to change color of ActionBar title using AppCompat.Light

Tags: android, colors, android-actionbar, styles, title

I've seen an amoung of posts about it and nothing works in my project.

This is my styles.xml:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

This provides me a beautiful interface like this:

I've tried a lot of things like defining:

@style/MyActionBar

And later I can redifine here the color of the title but later the colors declares previously desapear and the title doesn't turn it white (the color that I want).

I've searched everywhere and I hope somewho with the answer of this stupid and repeatly question.

Thanks, and sorry for the english.

Comment: Try this : [How do I change the background color of the ActionBar of an ActionBarActivity using XML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024706/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-of-the-actionbar-of-an-actionbaractivity-us)

Comment: I want to change the title color, the background is set with this:

<item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>