# How can i apply gradient in toolbar in android?

Tags: android

Explanation:
           I want to apply gradient on toolbar. I already did. I applied this gradient on my application theme in style.xml.

Here is my style.xml

```
<resources>

    <style name="MyMaterialTheme" parent="MyMaterialTheme.Base">

    </style>

    <style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@drawable/toolbar_gradient</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
    <style name="MyMaterialTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
    <style name="MyMaterialTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <style name="MyTabLayoutTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse">
        <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Here is my gradient.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:type="linear"
        android:startColor="@color/upper"
        android:endColor="@color/bottom"
        android:angle="270"/>
</shape>
```

Here is my color.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <color name="main_background">#FFFFFF</color>
    <!--009788  26A69A-->
    <color name="colorPrimary">#009788</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#E53935</color><!--00695C-->

    <color name="dull_color">#26A69A</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#3F51B5</color>
    <color name="textColorPrimary">#FFFFFF</color>`
    <color name="txtColor">#000000</color>
    <color name="windowBackground">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="navigationBarColor">#000000</color>
    <color name="counter_text_bg">#f32f32</color>
    <color name="list_background">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="sub_header">#CAF2E9</color>
    <color name="subHeader_text_colors">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="summary_sub_header">#EFF5F5</color>
    <color name="hor_line">#B2DFDB</color>
    <color name="spinner_bg_color">#B2DFDB</color>
    <color name="summary">#616161</color>
    <color name="score_header">#555555</color>    <!--#919191-->
    <color name="upper">#E15E5E</color>
    <color name="bottom">#991D1D</color>
    <color name="tab_background">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="indicator_color">#009788</color>  <!--#80CBC4-->
    <color name="tab_text">#000000</color>   <!--#FFFFFF-->
</resources>
```

Here is my splashScreen.java

```
public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static String Response_code = "", main_public_access_token = "", device_id = "", key_access_token = "device_id", expires = "";
    private static int statusCode;

    long hoursdiff = 0, minutesdiff = 0, diff = 0, daydiff = 0;
    String dateStart = "";
    SharedPreferences pref2;

    Date date1 = null;
    Date date2 = null;
    DateFormat dateFormatOld = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

        device_id = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
        dateFormatOld = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

        if (!Utils.isNetworkConnected(getApplicationContext())) {
            dialog_popup();
        } else {
            pref2 = this.getSharedPreferences("SaveTime", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            if (pref2.getString("oldDate", null) != null) {
                dateStart = pref2.getString("oldDate", null);
                try {
                    date1 = dateFormatOld.parse(dateStart);
                    date2 = dateFormatOld.parse(dateFormatOld.format(new Date()));

                    diff = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
                    daydiff = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
                    hoursdiff = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000) % 24;
                    minutesdiff = diff / (60 * 1000) % 60;

                    if (daydiff == 0) {
                        Log.e("daydiff zero", "" + daydiff);
                        if (hoursdiff <= 22) {
                            Log.e("hours diff small 22", "" + hoursdiff);
                            Log.e("22 TOKEN", "" + pref2.getString("accessToken", null));
                            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                                            MainActivity.class);
                                    i.putExtra(key_access_token, pref2.getString("accessToken", null));
                                    startActivity(i);
                                    finish();
                                }
                            }, 2000);
                        } else if (hoursdiff == 23) {
                            Log.e("hour equal 22", "" + hoursdiff);
                            if (minutesdiff <= 55) {
                                Log.e("55 less", "" + pref2.getString("accessToken", null));
                                Log.e("minutes less 55", "" + minutesdiff);
                                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                                                MainActivity.class);
                                        i.putExtra(key_access_token, pref2.getString("accessToken", null));
                                        startActivity(i);
                                        finish();
                                    }
                                }, 2000);
                            } else {
                                Log.e("hour more 22", "" + minutesdiff);
                                new ResponseService().execute();
                            }
                        }
                    } else if (daydiff >= 1) {
                        Log.e("day more 1", "" + daydiff);
                        new ResponseService().execute();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("pref zero", "DONE");
                new ResponseService().execute();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

When i installed my application this application not start and got an error.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.angelnx.cricvilla.cricvilla, PID: 21671
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.angelnx.cricvilla.cricvilla/com.angelnx.cricvilla.cricvilla.SplashScreen}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/toolbar_gradient.xml from color state list resource ID #0x7f0200e7
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3190)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3300)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:211)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1705)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6946)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

Comment: What is your shape file name it is `gradient.xml` or `toolbar_gradient.xml` please specify.

Comment: toolbar_gradient.xml

Comment: 1) It's called `colorPrimary` which is supposed to tell you to put a *color* resource in there, not a drawable. 2) You disabled the default action bar with the first two lines in your theme. 3) Use this http://stackoverflow.com/a/9249702/2444099 **without** the `android:` prefixes.

Comment: so tell me how to apply toolbar_gradient.xml which works in every version?

Comment: in v21 above style `colorPrimary` sense that you need to define only color name their.

Comment: you mean after v21 gradient not support?

Comment: please help me to solve out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`colorPrimary` should be given a color (which is actually just an integer) and you're using a `ShapeDrawable`.

if you want `gradient.xml` in the toolbar background, just use it on the toolbar background.

Change the color to an actual color

```
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
```

and on your Toolbar put the drawable as the background:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
      ... parameters...
      android:background="@drawable/gradient"
      />
```