# How do i change my default actionBar color?

Tags: android, material-design

I am running the latest eclipse with the latest Android support library, API 23. by default, the support library along with material design gets added to a new project as far as i know (Compile with API 23).

But i want to change the ActionBar's color, earlier [it was not possible on API <11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024706/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-of-the-actionbar-of-an-actionbaractivity-us) as it used android's built in library. now i am sure they added action bar in the support library as i tested my project on an android 2.3 device and i see the action bar, so compatibility is not an issue here.

So how do i change my action bar and button's colors?

EDIT::The suspected duplicate does Not solve my problem, i have tried that already, it gives me api level error when i define theme in the styles.xml. i have included the link in my question already.

Comment: eclipse has support of API 23?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change the background color of the ActionBar of an ActionBarActivity using XML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024706/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-of-the-actionbar-of-an-actionbaractivity-us)

Comment: actually yes (checked last time february). this isn't ADT bundle, and you can't update ADT bundle either, i downloaded everything individually.

Comment: why marked as duplicate?

Comment: Without code, xml layours and your theme is not clear what exactly you want to do. And duplicate link answers title question. And from context of question -> answers the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your styles.xml file.  The colorPrimary will be your action bar color and the colorPrimaryDark is the status bar color.

Note: Make sure this theme is set as your activities theme in your manifest.

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDarkDark</item>
</style>
```

Comment: yeah, AppTheme is set by default. BTW is it possible to change statusbar color in api 9

Comment: it didn't change the statusbar color on gingerbread, but it worked on lollipop. can you complete your answer? this is just the statusbar. how do i change other widget's color like buttons?

Comment: i have checked your answer, you will get an up vote if you complete it

Comment: I'm not sure as I haven't done that before, but try this
<item name="colorControlNormal">@color/splash_title</item>