# How to change the color theme of android app?

Tags: android, xml, colors, background-color

I’ve been following instructions on how to change the [color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024706/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-of-the-actionbar-of-an-actionbaractivity-us), but the program produces this error:

06-29 19:20:39.416 7041-7041/com.example.lucerne.adapter_example_2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

```
    Process: com.example.lucerne.adapter_example_2, PID: 7041
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.lucerne.adapter_example_2/com.example.lucerne.adapter_example_2.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
```

Currently, style.xml looks like below:

```
<!--<color name="white_opaque">#FFFFFFFF</color>-->
<!--<color name="pitch_black">#FF000000</color>-->

<!--<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">-->
    <!--<item name="android:background">@color/white_opaque</item>-->
    <!--<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white_opaque</item>-->
    <!--<item name="android:colorBackground">@color/white_opaque</item>-->

<!--</style>-->

 <!--Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<!--<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">-->
    <!--<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarTheme</item>-->
<!--</style>-->
<!--<style name="MyActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">-->
    <!--<item name="android:background">#FF0000</item>-->
<!--</style>-->
```

What is causing the error, and how I can change the colors to something else?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error says, you must **extend Theme.AppCompat** in your style.

Simple example like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
  </style>

 <style name="Theme.SemiTransparent" parent="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorSemiTransparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
  </style>
```

look at the style name at the first style, **AppTheme.NoActionBar**, it's using AppTheme as its base. Then in the second style, **AppTheme.NoActionBar**, it's using AppTheme with NoActionBar as its parent.

After you have using AppTheme as the base, you can change the color of your view with your custom style.