# How to change background color of action bar without increasing min sdk?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

As we know, a colored background of action bar permitted in sdk level 11, watch [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024706/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-of-the-actionbar-of-an-actionbaractivity-us?rq=1). But there are some applications with colored action bar that have min sdk lower than 11. For example Whatsapp has green action bar but has min sdk:7 [WhatsApp FAQ](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/21166563), or the Telegram application has min sdk:8 [Telegram FAQ](https://telegram.org/faq#q-which-devices-can-i-use), but has blue action bar.

How these applications work? And how I can do this?

```
android.app.ActionBar actionBar = (android.app.ActionBar) getActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
View mActionBarView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.action_bar_main, null);
actionBar.setCustomView(mActionBarView);
actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
```

This code requires minSdk = 11, for `getActionBar()`. Please help me.

Comment: They probably either use a library or may have their own implementation of the ActionBar (as a layout). Probably.

Comment: `setSupportActionBar`? That allows a min API 7 Toolbar, I believe

Answer (score 6):

the `Toolbar` (new name for the ActionBar introduced in Lollipop) is just a normal View.

Link: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html

you just set it's background like any other view.

```
// java
toolbar.setBackgroundColor(int color);
// or 
toolbar.setBackgroundResource(int resId);

// or XML
android:background="@drawable/toolbarBackground"
```

Comment: Link you provided for reference does not list `setBackgroundColor()` or `setBackgroundResource()` methods, or am I missing something?

Comment: @Talha apparently yes you're missing an important detail; official documentation link I provided shows that 'Toolbar' extends from 'View'. The setBackground methods are from the view class

Comment: I am not convinced by this. When I want to set a custom ActionBar with a xml layout, I should use getActionBar();. This us required in API 11.

Comment: If you really want want to use `getActionBar()` you first should call `set`. But that on the `AppCompatActivity is called `setSupportActionBar(Toolbar);` and `getSupportActionBar();`. But noticed that the `get` method will simply return the same object u passed before. That will be the `Toolbar`. Doc: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html#setSupportActionBar(android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar)

Comment: But please noticed that calls to `setSupportActionBar` and getSupportActionbar` are optional. You can do the same actions by simply directly accessing the `Toolbar` view, that you can just declared on your XML layout and use a `.NoActionBar` style.

Answer (score 0):

To change colour of your toolbar use this:

```
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.toolbar_color_primary)));
```