# how to change the actionbar color at runtime in android

Tags: android

I am trying to give a choice to the user to change the actionbar color at runtime but I can able to change the whole theme at runtime except the actionbar. Can anyone help me to change the actionbar color at runtime in android.

Comment: What approach do you use? Actionbar? Custom Toolbar?

Comment: Use `ToolBar` instead of `ActionBar`.

Comment: @piyush, ok, if I will use toolbar how can I change the color dynamically i.e at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (Hope you are suing Actionbar not Toolbar)

```
ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable("COLOR"));
```

Check this link for [more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024706/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-of-the-actionbar-of-an-actionbaractivity-us/8024797#8024797)

Comment: I am unable to change the color of actionbar  dynamically by using your code