# Action bar icon showing solid gray square in android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, icons, action-button

[This type of square is showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQrsn.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change the background color of the ActionBar of an ActionBarActivity using XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024706/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-of-the-actionbar-of-an-actionbaractivity-us)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to design a specific icon for the Action Bar, with solid color and transparency. You can create your notifications icons with this. https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html#source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&name=ic_stat_example