# Hide title of an activity with Dialog theme

Tags: android, android-actionbar, fatal-error

I need to hide or change color my activity action bar. But when I try to do this I got an error `FATAL EXCEPTION: main`.

My activity theme is `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog`

To hide

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

To change background color

```
android.app.ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.RED));
```

I am stuck with this error.

Error log

```
10-03 18:09:38.088 14160-14160/com.example.myown.myapplication 
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: com.example.myown.myapplication, PID: 14160

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myown.myapplication/com.example.myown.myapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2377)
```

Comment: how can we help with just error and setter code, kindly post getActionBar method completely, there will be some issue which is causing setter to scream.

Comment: Refer this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024706/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-of-the-actionbar-of-an-actionbaractivity-us

Comment: @MuhammadFaisalHyder i didnt get it

Comment: can you post full error log?

Comment: @Mehmed updated my qn with error log

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dialog theme do not have any `ActionBar`, use `Theme.AppCompat.Light`.

If you still want to use the Dialog theme and want to hide the title bar, call `supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` immediately after `super.onCreate`.

Comment: I need activity as half of the screen with transparency. so i use dialog theme.

Comment: in dialog theme there have an action bar

Comment: @JBR You will get null result if you call `getSupportActionBar()` in an activity with dialog theme. Which background are you trying to change?

Comment: then how we can hide it??