# How do I change the background color of the ActionBar in the new MaterialComponents

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-styles, material-components-android

I'm using the new [MaterialComponents](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android) and my app theme is:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDarkColor</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/secondaryColor</item>
</style>
```

how to change the background color of ActionBar

I know about [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024706/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-of-the-actionbar-of-an-actionbaractivity-us) but it's outdated and doesn't use `MaterialComponents`

I don't want to add Toolbar to every screen just to change the background color.

Answer (score 8):

You need use `ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.ActionBar` or `ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dark.ActionBar` depending on the background color.

```
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDarkColor</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/secondaryColor</item>
        <item name="actionBarTheme">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">#fff</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 3):

I know it's already too late.

According to [Material Component](https://material.io/components/app-bars-top#theming). You have to add in your AppTheme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">
    <!--  This will change ActionBar BackgroundColor to Black -->
    <item name="colorSurface">#000000</item>

    <!--  This will change ActionBar TextColor to White  -->
    <item name="colorOnSurface">#FFFFFF</item>
</style
```

NOTE: If you create your project from template with action bar,
check your file: res/layout/app_bar_main.xml
Make sure to delete:
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" in <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar /> as shown below:

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

   <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
       android:id="@+id/toolbar"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
  android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" <<== MAKE SURE YOU DELETE THIS ONE LINE
       app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

Otherwise, the ActionBar BackgroundColor will depend on: ?attr/colorPrimary

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using a `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light` app theme the ActionBar background color is defined by default by the **`colorPrimary`** attribute.

Just use the **`actionBarTheme`** attribute to override the background color:

```
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">
    <item name="actionBarTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.ActionBar</item>
    ...
  </style>
```

with:

```
  <style name="ThemeOverlay.ActionBar" parent="">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/mycolor</item>
  </style>
```

You can also customize the background color using the **`actionBarStyle`** attribute in your app theme.

Something like:

```
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.*">
      <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Custom.ActionBar</item>
      ...
  </style>
```

In this case you can use the `background` attribute:

```
  <style name="Custom.ActionBar" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="background">@color/mycolor</item>
  </style>
```