# StatusBar does not show when setting actionBarStyle

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-manifest, android-styles

I'm trying to change the action bar in my activities via XML.

As suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9249702/4687402) and similar answers, I defined two styles. One `AppTheme` to set in the activities (or application) tag in my manifest file. The other to define the action bar itself, `MyActionBarTheme`. Very simply:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#F00</item>
</style>
```

I set the AppTheme for the whole app:

```
<application android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".settings.DeleteAccountActivity"
              android:label="Delete Account">
    </activity>
...
```

I even tried to specifically set the theme for my activity:

```
<application android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".settings.DeleteAccountActivity"
              android:label="Delete Account"
              android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    </activity>
...
```

which I know is redundant.

What happens is this:

If I don't set the actionBarStyle, I see the standard action bar. However, If I set my actionBarStyle, the actionBar disappears completely.

I've tried some other things, like

`<item name="actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/MyActionBarTheme</item>`

and `<item name="actionBarTheme">@style/MyActionBarTheme</item>`

or specifically setting `<item name="windowActionBar">true</item>`

and using

```
<style name="MyActionBarTitleText"
       parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">#F00</item>
</style>
```

but the same thing happens. The action bar disappears completely. Any idea as to what causes this and how I can fix this?

### Update

I just noticed that I set "actionBarStyle" and not "android:actionBarStyle". But when I do write the "android:", it still doesn't take `MyActionBarTheme`, but instead looks just like I haven't set "actionBarStyle" at all.